# linked attributes between classes (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, sum, attr

Good morning, I'm having an issue in my rails app when trying to link attributes between two classes. Let me explain better:

I have a `System`class, which `belongs_to` my `Area` class (one area `has_many` systems). Both of them have an attribute called `price`. The price of an area must be the sum of the prices of all the systems it has.

Is there any way to make this relation without having to update the area's price every time I change one of it system's price? (I do something like `@system.area.price = @system.area.price + @system.price`)

Comment: You do **not** want `area.price` to automatically update?

Comment: @dax no, exactly the opposite. That's just what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with handling this in the database, the `sum` calculation will do it for you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :systems
  def price
    systems.sum('price')
  end
end
```

You could remove the Area's price field altogether.

Comment: It depends if you want to display this in a list, because this will result in N queries instead of 1 when displaying multiple area records.

Comment: You betcha, something a competent developer would pay attention to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to go down the dark, dangerous road of introducing triggers into your database, short answer is not really.

The long answer is you need to have `after_save` handlers that do this adjustment for you. Always be sure that the way you're applying this does an *increment* and not a *reset* or you will have race conditions.

In your short example it's not clear what you're asking for. Unless Area has a `base_price` then you'll keep adding on the System price indefinitely. You'll need to work out the exact logic here, but an example of your requirements are:

```
class System < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :area
  after_save :update_area_price

protected
  def update_area_price
    self.area and self.area.increment!(:price, self.price)
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean with `base_price`? What I want is to create a relation between the `area.price` and its `system` prices (where `area.price` is equal to the sum of its systems prices.

Comment: Then you'll need a way of reconciling this. Set `area.price` to be `SUM(systems.price)` with the right scope: `self.price = self.systems.sum(:price)`, perhaps?

Comment: it worked using `sum`, thanks a lot @tadman! with the concept understood, I made a loop (using `each`) that worked better!